# JSP calling method Servlet

Tags: java, forms, jsp, servlets, post

I would like to have an input 'submit' calling a method from the Java EE java servlet that is responsible for showing the JSP.

```
<form action="????" method="post">
     <input type="image" src="img/icons/cross.png" alt="Remove widget">
</form>
```

The above form method (another solution is also welcome) should alert the Servlet and include the id of the widget that has to be removed. How can I accomplish something like this, without using scriptlets and with using a MVC set-up.

The servlet included the widgets in the JSP by using the following line of code:

```
request.setAttribute("widgets", widgets);
```

Thanks:)

Comment: Have you tried by replacing question marks with servlet path?

Comment: You want to interact with your servlet using ajax or similar (respecting the MVC pattern) to remove the image from your page?

Comment: No, not only from the page. I should have been clearer. The point is to ask the controller/servlet to remove the widget from the database

Comment: Ok, what have you tried? If you don't have any idea on how to do this, you can visit [our Servlet wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

Comment: You will need to include an hidden input containing the ID of the widget you want to delete. In your servlet you will be able to parse this ID and delete the good one. It would be easier in JSF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys. With the suggestion of Alexandre I managed to fix my problem:)